# Application Insights Trace Listener for ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-application-insights

I have a bunch of services which emit `System.Diagnostics.Trace.*` trace messages.  When hosted via ASP.NET WebAPI, I simply include the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener` package and my custom traces from the service libs are collected in app insights.

However, I cannot figure out how to get these same messages when hosting the services via ASP.NET Core 2.0 WebAPI.  What I've tried...

#### Add Application Insights

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Information);
     //...
    }
```

After adding application insights using the extension method, I am able to see the traces emitted by the framework (eg, Request Start, Request End, ...), but none of my custom trace messages are present.

#### Add Trace Listener Package

I decided to add in the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener` package just to see if that would help.  I updated the configure method to look like this...

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddTraceSource(new System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch("AppInsightsTraceSwitch")
        {
            Level = System.Diagnostics.SourceLevels.All
        }, new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener.ApplicationInsightsTraceListener());

        loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Information);
    }
```

After updating the configuration, I now see the trace messages duplicated in the logs, but none of the custom traces are present still.

Here is the [issue on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/589#issuecomment-372754260).  Here is a [sample repo](https://github.com/spelltwister/AspNetCoreAppInsightsTrace) with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

TraceListener support for .Net Core is now available in the latest stable `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener` - 2.6.4.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener/